# How to uninstall Joplin if you don't know how it was installed?

Tags: 20.04, package-management

I installed Joplin the markdown editor some time ago and now I want to remove it.

I checked Ubuntu Software and it is not under the installed tab (and it still gives the option to install it on its page). I used `sudo apt remove joplin` and it says there is no apt package with that name but there is a snap. I used `sudo snap remove joplin` and it says joplin is not installed

I used `apt list`, `snap list` and `dpkg -l` to find it and it is not included in those lists.

It is definitely there and running, how can I locate and remove it please? Using Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: Try the commands `which joplin` and `whereis joplin` and add the output to your Question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Joplin is often [installed manually](https://github.com/laurent22/joplin), though there are Snap and Flatpak options available. To remove a manually installed Joplin installation, you can follow these steps:

0. Open Terminal (if it’s not already open)
1. Remove Joplin:

   ```
   sudo rm -r ~/.joplin
   sudo rm -r ~/.config/joplin-desktop
   sudo rm ~/.local/share/applications/appimagekit-joplin.desktop
   ```
2. Enjoy a coffee

Comment: Thank you! That did it.